# Best to store dynamic data and dynamic things in android

Tags: android, database, database-design

the scenario is that -- in my application client would make dynamic edit text (of which i m not sure ), but i want to store all the information he creates. All other part have been done.
I just want to know which is the best way to store them **in File OR in Database**.
As if some says in Database, i want to know how?
and if in File, why?
I will encrypt and decry pt the data too.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in a database. If you're doing Android development, simply use SQLite - http://www.sqlite.org/.

There are many reasons *not* to store the data on the file system:

1. It is easier to query a database than a file system. You can quickly and easily answer questions like "How many records do I have?" or "How many items in a given category do I have?" 
   If you do this in the file system, you'll have to write your own code around querying.
2. SQLite has strong data types that enforce a schema. If you just write to a file, you'll have to ensure an ID is an integer etc. The database can do this for you.
3. From my experience when writing files to the file system, I've always ended up with orphaned files. You write them and then forget they are there and they never get deleted. It's annoying. With a database you can easily assess the state of the database and remove old/unused records.